Complex measure on $\mathbb{C}$
When people talk about complex measure on $\mathbb{C}$, is there a conventional one?
For example, the theorem below is from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis:

Suppose $\mu$ is a complex measure on a measurable space $X$, $\varphi$ is a complex measurable function, $\Omega$ is an open set which does not intersect $\varphi(X)$, and $$f(z)= \int_{X} \dfrac{\mathrm{d}\mu(\zeta)}{\varphi(\zeta)-z}.$$ Then $f$ is representable by power series in $\Omega$.

When I want to apply it to $\mathbb{C}$, which complex measure should I choose?

usually complex measure is implicitly defined to be finite - in other words when you decompose $\mu=\mu_1-\mu_2+i(\mu_3-\mu_4)$ with "minimal" positive measures $\mu_{1,2,3,4}$ (eg $\mu_1=\Re^+ \mu=\max (\Re \mu, 0)$ etc) then $\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3+\mu_4$ is a finite positive measure; you also can take the above the definition of a complex measure - so one takes $4$ finite positive measures $\mu_{1,2,3,4}$ and defines $\mu$ as above

@Conrad please give me a detailed example.

for example take $\mu=\delta_0-\delta_1+i(\delta_{2i}-\delta_{3i})$ so $mu(A)=1$ is $0 \in A$ but $1,2i, 3i \in A$ but $\mu(A)=-i$ if $3i \in A$ but not the other points are in $A$ etc etc

When you consider a measure (positive or complex) "on" some set, it is implicitly assumed to be equipped with a sigma-algebra. For a topological space like $\mathbb C,$ unless otherwise stated, that would be the sigma-algebra generated by the open sets.
In Rudin's theorem, the term "complex measure" does not refer to the underlying space, which can be any measurable space, but the fact that the measure takes complex values, usually defined as a complex linear combination of four finite positive measures. Depending on the author the finiteness condition may be dropped.
There are many such measures on the base space $\mathbb C,$ and there is no obvious default choice; for example any complex integrable function on $\mathbb R^2$ could be interpreted as such a finite measure by taking the integral of the function over any given measurable set.

However, when we combine the theorem with Cauchy's formula, it implies that any holomorphic function can be represented by power series. Then what is the complex measure here? Or when you calculate complex integrals, you do have chosen some complex measure right?

Cauchy's formula traditionally involves integration over a curve in the complex plane. Of course a measure that is concentrated on a (real one-dimensional) curve is technically a "measure on $\mathbb C$" but it's misleading because that curve is itself a null set in Lebesgue measure. The complex measure in this case can be expressed as a complex function multiplied by the (positive) arc length measure. In the Cauchy formula the complex function would be the derivative of the curve (with respect to arc length) multiplied by the function for which we want to prove that it's holomorphic.

Thanks. Anyway, the complex measure appears in a strange way in complex analysis.
